# Perl LWP does not work

Tags: perl, lwp

I'm using Padre as my IDE with Strawberry Perl on Windows 7 Pro.

I'm trying to create a perl script that goes to a text file on a website, and then reads/copies the text file.

But I can't get LWP to work even for the simplest LWP command ever.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
   use strict;
   use warnings;
   use LWP::Simple;

   getprint('http://www.perlmeme.org') or die 'Unable to get page';

   exit 0;
```

I keep getting this error message:
500 can't connect to proxy.sn.no:8001 (Bad hostname) 
eg 500 can't connect to  (Bad hostname) http://www.perlmeme.org

I've been googling around, used Microsoft Fixit to reset ports, etc but I still can't make it work. http//www.justskins.com/forums/lwp-connect-failing-bad-119421.html

Can anyone help me out here? Been stuck for many hours :(

Edit:

--1 foreach my $key (keys %ENV) { print "$key: $ENV{$key}\n" if $key =~ m/proxy/i; }

Yes it prints out FTP_PROXY and HTTP_PROXY both followed by this: http://proxy.sn.no:8001/

That's the proxy that I got from this helpthread [How do I install a module? Strawberry Perl issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611382/how-to-install-module-strawberry-perl-issues)

I had the proxy problem, then I tried the config from that thread, then the proxy problem was still there.

--2 I'm not expecting any proxy to be used on my end or anything. Just wanna connect the perl script to the website to retrieve a text document.

--3 ping  had 0% loss. (I can only post two hyperlinks in this post)

--4 I'm using Windows.

Comment: Does `foreach my $key (keys %ENV) { print "$key: $ENV{$key}\n" if $key =~ m/proxy/i; }` print anything? (I ask because `LWP::Simple` is documented to take its proxy settings from environment variables named things like `*_proxy`.)

Comment: Are you expecting a proxy to be used on your end? It's not clear whether your problem is that you're using a proxy you shouldn't be using or it's that you're having problems connecting to the proxy you should be using.

Comment: Try `ping www.perlmeme.org` to see if you can even connect to that server.

Answer (score 1):

LWP will honor the `http_proxy` environment variable and try to use it as an HTTP proxy.  Check with `env | grep http_proxy` on Unix.

Comment: @JohnTan You are using a proxy, and it is broken.  Turn it off.  If you're stuck behind a firewall, find a new proxy or talk to your firewall administrator to allow the connection you need.

Comment: How do I turn off the proxy? I'm using ZoneAlarm firewall but I've already closed it from the taskbar (the area near the volume).

I am the only user of this computer.

Comment: Unset the HTTP_PROXY and FTP_PROXY environment variables!

Comment: I entered unset http_proxy into the cmd line and I had this error message:

'unset' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: @JohnTan I don't know much about managing environment variables on Windows. You'll have to do some Googling and reading or maybe ask a question on superuser.com.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519 is a start.