# Installing strawberry perl in windows

Tags: perl

I have installed perl in windows 7 and configured the proxy (http & ftp) as at [How do I install a module? Strawberry Perl issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611382/how-to-install-module-strawberry-perl-issues) by Axeman, replacing proxy with my lan proxy IP and port respectively. However, when I run cpanm App::cpanminus, it returns a message for proxy authentication which has faile. Its requesting for a username.

Comment: I think cpanm is App::cpanminus, you need to use cpan first.

Comment: @squiguy I have used `cpan App::cpanminus` in cmd prompt

Comment: what username @Quentin , am new to perl

Comment: The username for your proxy server

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the http_proxy environment variable in the form:

```
http_proxy=http://user:password@host:port/
```

Otherwise just use the `cpan` client.

---

Edit: 2012-08-29

If you do not have the proxy username and password, you are not getting out through that proxy regardless of the client software.

Comment: On Windows, that command would be `set http_proxy=http://user:password@host:port/`. AFAIK you can't define Env vars inline with your command on Windows.

Comment: the reason am stuck is that am in a lan with a proxy server which we dont have the usernm and psswrd for. Does it then mean that there is no way to get cpan working?

Comment: Did you try setting the proxy without username/password? Like `set http_proxy=http://host:port/` ?

Comment: @wes just did that and run cpan App::cpanminus which again ask for proxy authentication requesting a username. I don't know the username nor password.

Comment: @user1498499 Sorry, I've never used cpanm with proxy so I'm out of suggestions. You can ask on #toolchain at irc.perl.org for some help.