# Error on CPAN installation

Tags: module, installation, cpan

When i tried installing the Perl Modules from CPAN in Strawberry perl with windows 7 OS using the command

"cpan Text::Extract"

i got the Following Error, "Fetching with LWP: http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
LWP failed with code[500] message[Can't connect to cpan.strawberryperl.com:80 (10060)]
Warning: no success downloading 'C:\strawberry\cpan\sources\authors\01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp5668'. Giving up on it."

What is the cause of this Error and how to resolve it?

Comment: Sounds like a remote error - does it still happen for you?

Comment: Yes Rowland..it is still happening to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the Error with the help of the information from,
[How do I install a module? Strawberry Perl issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611382/how-to-install-module-strawberry-perl-issues?answertab=active#tab-top)

But One thing They missed out Or assuming that the user will know it is how to get Address and port Value respective to theor PC's.
you can get this info from the browser as follows,
Tools -> Internet Options-> Connections -> LAN Settings -> Address and Port Values mentioned under "Proxy Server" Tab.
so for Eg: if you find Address: XX.YY.XX.WW and port value as :8002,
 the using CPAN shell you can configure the value for "http_proxy" as follows

o conf http_proxy http://XX.YY.XX.WW :8002/

This Resolves my issue.